# Android Validators fields

Tags: android

i have made the many layout in android.
kindly tell me the best and easy way to validate the input field before save the data into the database.
Like Required field.
data should be in number etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for input must be number you use this at your `EditText`

```
android:inputType="number"
```

for required field you can use :

```
 private boolean isEmpty(EditText editText) {
        boolean isEmpty = false;
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText())) {
            isEmpty = true;
            editText.setError("Empty field");
        }

        return isEmpty
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find validation library [here](https://github.com/thyrlian/AwesomeValidation) and [here](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar)